# \NewDocumentCommand without xparse

Tags: xparse, latex-base, definition

I noticed that I can use `\NewDocumentCommand` without loading `xparse`.
Why is that?
How universal is that?
And where can I read more about this? (My search terms always pointed to `xparse`.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\NewDocumentCommand\abc{}{aabbcc}
\abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the 2020-10-01, `\NewDocumentCommand` is available in the kernel. You need `xparse` only to support the deprecated argument types.

Comment: It is still probably a ggod idea to load xparse anyways, just in case you need to send the document to someone else, someone who haven't updated their latex in a while

Comment: @daleif In a package, I'd encourage `\@ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}{}{\RequirePackage{xparse}}` as that way you load it _only_ if  required

Comment: @JosephWright I agree, just cumbersome in the preamble of a doc.

Comment: @daleif Well for that I'd be likely to use `\ifdefined\NewDocumentCommand\RequirePackage{xparse}\fi`, as whilst it's not formal LaTeX syntax, it's short

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of `xparse` was integrated into the LaTeX kernel with the 2020-10-01 release, so now it's officially part of LaTeX.  I'm not sure I understand your “How universal is that” question, but if I do, the change should be permanent and available in all recent LaTeX formats.

You can read more about it on [`ltnews32`](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb41-3/tb129ltnews32.pdf):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In general to learn about LaTeX improvements and fixes

- use `texdoc ltnews` on your distribution (giving you all newsletters as a single pdf)
- or use `texdoc ltnews<number>` if you know the latest number (for this release it was 33)
- visit [the LaTeX Project website](https://www.latex-project.org) once in a while
- subscribe to our "news" there (we only send out a handful per year)