# How to provide xparse on both old and recent latex distributions

Tags: xparse

I wrote [a library](https://github.com/leo-colisson/proof-at-the-end/) which requires a recent enough `xparse` version. Because I would like my package to be as portable as possible, I included (in the git repository only) a copy of a recent enough `xparse.sty`: that way (more or less) anybody cloning my repository could compile the demo directly.

However, it seems that on new LaTeX distributions, xparse is "built-in" (not sure if it's technically true), and therefore compiling something as simple as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

will fail with the following error (assuming you put the file `xparse.sty` available for instance [here](https://github.com/leo-colisson/proof-at-the-end/blob/c2150f4feba4709d47e43c00e5f8eb93ce345cab/xparse.sty)):

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence \l__xparse_arg_spec_tl already defined.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.37 \tl_new:N \l__xparse_arg_spec_tl
                                     
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.37 \tl_new:N \l__xparse_arg_spec_tl
                                     
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on demo.log.
```

Is there a way (maybe by changing the `xparse.sty` file?) to use the system xparse if it is more recent than `2019-03-05`, and use the provided `xparse.sty` otherwise? I tried to put a `\@ifpackagelater{xparse}{2019-03-05}{}{...}` around the whole file, but then I get another error:

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1736 ...e_all:Nnn \l__xparse_split_list_tl { ^^@
```

Comment: Quite apart from the technical issue, there is a license one - you can't distribute just the `.sty` file ...

Comment: don't provide local versions of such styles. That is a pain for the users. Either write your code so that it works also with older xparse, or require a current tex system.

Comment: “not sure if it's technically true”: it is. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/600353/134574.  `xparse` was carefully modified to be compatible with recent LaTeX, which already have the code built in, so your “recent enough” version is not recent enough for LaTeX since last year. I'd suggest you require a recent system (that's not a big issue nowadays)

Comment: You also can, of course, just not load `xparse` if it's already there: `\@ifundefined{NewDocumentCommand}{\usepackage{xparse}}{}`, but that still leaves the license issue

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your help, I'll try to remove the xparse and provide instructions for users of older distributions. Thanks!

Comment: In my experience the best instruction you can give to users of older distributions is: I don't support old systems. Sounds heartless or rude, but there is a limit to what you can reasonably support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `\usepackage{xparse}` in your document and don't distribute your own copy then the document will work in any tex distribution from the last 10 years or so,  There is no advantage at all in distributing a version of xparse. Each distribution of whatever age will have a compatible version of xparse.

If you use

```
\usepackage{xparse}[2020-01-01]
```

or whatever date you choose then users will get an error message if their xparse is too old for your library.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that the 'basic' argument types (`m`, `o`, `O`, `s`) and `+` syntax have been there for at least a decade if not longer. So unless one needs say `e`-type arguments, any at-all-recent `xparse` will be fine.

Comment: I need to use the `b` argument type, and this one is quite recent (it was not present in 2018, making it hard to import in overleaf which was using 2018 distribution by default). But I guess I'll do that, thanks.

Comment: @tobiasBora overleaf has texlive 2020 by default for all new projects and you can switch old projects to that. I just tested a `b` definition on overleaf and it works fine https://www.overleaf.com/read/pmhrrbcnsdzy

Comment: Yeah I know, I just updated the code thanks!